# error No profiles when using CircleCI archive iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, circleci, fastlane

I'm using CircleCI to execute fastlane to export AdHoc ipa.

I can install *.p12 into CircleCI container then it works until archive. Provisioning Profiles recreated in Apple Developer Console but I think it can't automatic download because it not developer machine. How can I do ?

- How can I set xcode developer account, for `allowProvisioningUpdates`
- How can I specify *.mobileprovision in `gym()`

fastlane output:

```
2022-04-21 11:26:01.316 xcodebuild[4722:18710] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
▸ Clean Succeeded

❌  error: No profiles for 'com.example.lordgiftapp.sit' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.example.lordgiftapp.sit'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild. (in target 'LordGift App' from project 'LordGift App')

** ARCHIVE FAILED **
[11:26:54]: Exit status: 65
```

My Fastfile look like this,

```
sigh(
    adhoc: true,
    force: true,
    provisioning_name: "LordGift App SIT AdHoc"
)
gym(
    clean: true,
    export_method: "ad-hoc",
    project: "LordGift App.xcodeproj",
    scheme: "LordGift App",
    configuration: "Debug",
    skip_profile_detection: true,
    export_options: {
        provisioningProfiles: {
            "com.example.lordgiftapp.sit" => "LordGift App SIT AdHoc"
        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my Xcode project > Signing & Capabilities still 'None'. I download profile and select it to 'LordGift App SIT AdHoc'.